# Parse URL which contain string of two URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, express

I've node app and Im getting in some header the following URL and I need to **parse it** and change the content of 3000 to 4000 ,How can I do that since Im getting "two" URLs in the `req.headers.location`

"http://to-d6faorp:51001/oauth/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3AF%2Fmo-d6fa3.ao.tzp.corp%3A3000%2Flogin%2Fcallback&client_id=x2.node"

The issue is that I cannot use just replace since the value can changed (dynmaic value ,now its 3000 later can be any value...)

Comment: does the redirect_uri site change.  If not you could parse http%3AF%2Fmo-d6fa3.ao.tzp.corp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the part of the URL you always need to change is going to be a parameter of redirect_uri then you just need to find the index of the second %3A that comes after it.

Javascript indexOf has a second parameter which is the 'start position', so you can first do an indexOf the 'redirect_uri=' string, and then pass that position in to your next call to indexOf to look for the first '%3A' and then pass that result into your next call for the %3A that comes just before your '3000'. Once you have the positions of the tokens you are looking for you should be able to build a new string by using substrings... first substring will be up to the end of your second %3A and the second substring will be from the index of the %2F that comes after it.

Basically, you will be building your string by cutting up the string like so:

"http://to-d6faorp:51001/oauth/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3AF%2Fmo-d6fa3.ao.tzp.corp%3A"

"%2Flogin%2Fcallback&client_id=x2.node"

... and appending in whatever port number you are trying to put in.

Hope this helps.

This code should get you what you want:

```
var strURL = "http://to-d6faorp:51001/oauth/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3AF%2Fmo-d6fa3.ao.tzp.corp%3A3000%2Flogin%2Fcallback&client_id=x2.node";

var strNewURL = strURL.substring(0,strURL.indexOf("%3A", strURL.indexOf("%3A", strURL.indexOf("redirect_uri") + 1) + 1) + 3) + "4000" + strURL.substring(strURL.indexOf("%2F",strURL.indexOf("%3A", strURL.indexOf("%3A", strURL.indexOf("redirect_uri") + 1) + 1) + 3));
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give example how you change the value from 3000 to 4000?

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing ALL your work for you, thought the explanation was good enough to get you started. But the code I added as an edit should help.

Comment: Please style the coding passages as `code`, that looks awful

Comment: @jcaruso - 2 issue one when I use your code I got error unexpected token 2. this is too specific I guess since you are refering to "%3A" and "%2F" can this be avoided?

Comment: @jcaruso Regard the first issue I've add ) which solve the issue but its too specific...

Comment: %3A is the colon for your port number. If you're always trying to change the port number then you can pretty much guarantee that that'll be there. Same with the %2F, that is the slash '/', it'll be there too. But if your sample URL was just made up and it'll never follow the same format EVER then there is no way you'll be able to do this. Unless you're always changing an arbitrary 3000 to some other value.

Answer (score 0):

Split the return string in its parameters:

```
var parts = req.headers.location.split("&");
```

then split the parts into fieldname and variable:

```
var subparts = [];
for (var i = 1; i < parts.length; i++)
    subparts[i] = parts[i].split("=");
```

then check which fieldname equals `redirect_uri`:

```
var ret = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < subparts.length; i++)
    if (subpart[i][0] == "redirect_uri")
        ret = i;

if (ret == -1)
    // didnt find redirect_uri, somehow handle this error
```

now you know which subpart contains the `redirect_uri`.

Because I dont know which rules your `redirect_uri` follows I can't tell you how to get the value, thats your task but the problem is isolated to `subparts[ret][1]`. Thats the string which contains `redirect_uri`.

Comment: Thanks I try it but I was not able to change the value,any idea?